# Best way to import and/or upgrade Oracle database

Tags: oracle-11g-r2

I have an Oracle database, version 11.2.0.3.6. I need to export that database and import it in a 11.2.0.3.15 home on another server. What's preferred?

1) Just export/import the old database on a newly created instance running 11.2.0.3.15?

2) Upgrade the old database to 11.2.0.3.15, and then do the export/import to the new server?

3) Any other suggestion?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. That is possible.
2. Not really needed. You can just simply transfer the database to the new server, and run the PSU postinstall script there, that takes like 1 minute.
3. Depends on some factors:

   - platform of the old and new systems
   - size of the database + hardware environment (network/disk transfer speed and CPU power)
   - downtime allowed
   - Standard or Enterprise edition
   - archivelog mode enabled
   - have backups
   - need the current state of the database on the new server, or yesterday evening is good enough
   - can use licensed extra products

Some other methods:

- RMAN restore from backup (and run the PSU postinstall script)
- RMAN duplicate from active database or backup (and run the PSU postinstall script)
- RMAN transportable tablespace/database
- configure Streams replication and switch to new database
- configure GoldenGate replication and switch to new database
- configure the new host as a Data Guard standby then perform a role transition (and run the PSU postinstall script)

There is no best method. It depends on your actual task/environment.

Comment: Thanks Balazs Papp, so if I use option 1), do I need to run the PSU post installation scripts? This is EE, by the way.

Comment: @neutrino Not needed. Before you export or import anyhting, create an empty database on the new server, and apply the latest PSU (install and run postinstallation script). After that you do not need to care about it anymore. With export + import you transfer user data, and that is not touched by the PSU scripts.